# Where to load common data in an application with authentication

Tags: ember.js

I have an application with a sidebar which is always visible. For this sidebar I have to load common data once. This is usually not a problem, I do this in the `setupController` hook of the `ApplicationRoute`.

```
Tedian.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: ->
    controller = @controllerFor("sidebar")
    controller.set "tasks", @store.find("task")
    controller.set "projects", @store.find("project")
    controller.set "timeEntries", @store.find("timeEntry")

    Tedian.TimeEntry.findActive().then (timeEntry) ->
      controller.set "activeTimeEntry", timeEntry
```

**But where do I put this setup code in an application with authentication?**

I don't want to run this code for an un-authenticated user so I can't put it into the `ApplicationRoute`. Where is the best place to put it instead?

Comment: How do you will do the authentication logic? Using some framework or by hand etc.

Comment: I'm doing it by hand, similar to this: http://log.simplabs.com/post/53016599611/authentication-in-ember-js

Comment: it would go in App.SessionsNewRoute createSession action then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps i'm too stupid here, but i would simply check if the user is logged in:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

   initializeSidebar: function() {
      if (!App.user.get('isSignedIn')) return;
      var controller = this.controllerFor('sidebar');
      //...
   }.observes('App.user.isSignedIn'),

   setupController: function(controller, model) {
       controller.set('model', model);
       this.initializeSidebar();
   }
});
```

Now, if the user signs in or the user is already signed in, but the information about that comes asynchronously, the sidebar gets updated.

I don't know if it's a good practice to store the user object directly on the App, but as you want access it from everywhere anyways, i think it's ok. Alternatively have it as an attribute of a controller that you then can access from the ApplicationRoute by calling `this.controllerFor('')`

Comment: I did something very similar where my login controller would dispatch an event which is catched at the `ApplicationRoute`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the user is authenticated when the app boots

```
App.initializer({
  name: 'bootstrap',
  initialize: function() {
    //if user is authenticated do a $.ajax or 2 in here
  }
});
```

Comment: What happens when I'm not authenticated when the app boots but I sign in after that? A sign in doesn't cause an page load so the boot logic already happened.

Comment: ah yes - this would require another type of action driven by another component

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you'll want to have a User model that has several hasMany relationships with your Task, Project and TimeEntry models.  Then, when you authenticate your user, however you do that, the server response should include those related models.

Then your SidebarController can have a controller need for the current user:

```
App.SidebarController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ["currentUser"]
});
```

And your sidebar template can have something like

```
{{render "tasks" currentUser.tasks}}
{{render "projects" currentUser.projects}}
{{render "timeEntries" currentUser.timeEntries}}
```

And those will populate automatically when you set the currentUser with the appropriate data.

If you don't have control over the server response, then you can have an observer on the currentUserController fetch that stuff after authentication.